# How do I make sure the errors object in React-Hook-Form is the correct type in a nested object form?

Tags: react-hook-form

I'm getting type errors showing that properties that should be in the `errors` object are not defined. Here are some example types and how my form is set up.

```
type InputsA = {
   value1: {
        active: boolean,
        weight: number,
   },
    value2: {
        active: boolean,
        weight: number,
   }
   value3: {
        active: boolean,
        weight: number,
   }
}

type InputsB = {
   value1: '',
   value2: '',
   value3: ''
}

type InputsC = {
   value1: '',
   value2: '',
   value3: ''
}

type Calculator = {
   id: 2;
   ...
   inputs: InputsA | Inputs B | InputsC;


const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
    control,
    reset,
} = useForm<Calculator>({ defaultValues: INITIAL_CALCULATOR });
const [calculatorLabel, calculatorType, inputs] = useWatch({ control, name: ['label', 'type', 'inputs'] });


//Example input

<TextField
    type='number'
    disabled={!(inputs as InputsA).value1.active}
    defaultValue={(inputs as InputsA).value1.weight}
    size='small'
    variant='outlined'
    // ERROR HAPPENS HERE. value1 doesn't exist on the error type
    error={!!errors.inputs?.value1!.weight?.message}
    helperText={errors.inputs?.value1!.weight?.message}
    InputProps={
        {
            endAdornment: <InputAdornment position='end'>%</InputAdornment>,
        }
    }
    {...register('inputs.value1.weight', { ...VALIDATION_RULES.summaryInputs })}
/>
```

From my assumption, the react-hook-form should take the type, in my case `Calculator`, and create the error type from that automatically. I think the issue comes from the inputs possibly being one of multiple types. The `TextField` example shows how I currently have the `error` and `helperText` set up. It's currently using the `error` object that is set up using the `formState`.  When running the code it shows the type error when initializing saying that `value1` doesn't exist on the error object, but error does populate like it should when it is created by submitting the input. So I'm wondering if there is a way to pass the type to errors? Or if I just need to reassign Errors to a particular type?

I have tried creating a specific type to force the `error` object to like...

```
type InputsAErrors = {
   value1: {
      active: {
          type: 'error',
          message: 'This is an error.',
      }
      weight: {
          type: 'error',
          message: 'This is an error.',
      }
   }
}

<TextField
    type='number'
    disabled={!(inputs as InputsA).value1.active}
    defaultValue={(inputs as InputsA).value1.weight}
    size='small'
    variant='outlined'
    // ERROR HAPPENS HERE. value1 doesn't exist on the error type
    error={!!(errors.inputs as InputsAErrors)?.value1!.weight?.message}
    helperText={(errors.inputs as InputsAErrors)?.value1!.weight?.message}
    InputProps={
        {
            endAdornment: <InputAdornment position='end'>%</InputAdornment>,
        }
    }
    {...register('inputs.value1.weight', { ...VALIDATION_RULES.summaryInputs })}
/>
```

But this was definitely wrong and caused it's own issues.

Appreciate the help and guidance.